# Killing vector fields restricted to geodesics

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$, a Killing vector field $X$ on $M$, and a geodesic $\gamma: K \rightarrow M$ defined on an interval $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, how does one show that $X \circ \gamma$ is a Jacobi field along $\gamma$?

Answer (score 6):

Wlog $\gamma = \gamma(t)$ is parameterized by arclength. Then this is shown by differentiating $X\circ \gamma$ twice wRt $t$, using the defining equations for a geodesic and Killing field and the rules for interchanging covariant derivates -- these, you need to know, of course. Differentiating once results in:
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} X\circ\gamma = \nabla_{\gamma^{\prime}} X = \nabla_X \gamma^{\prime}$$
the last equality being true cause $X$  is killing (implying that the Lie derivative $[X,\gamma^{\prime}]$ vanishes). Hence
$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}  \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}} X\circ\gamma = 
\nabla_{\gamma^{\prime}} \nabla_X \gamma^{\prime} = \nabla_X \nabla_{\gamma^{\prime}} \gamma^{\prime} + R(\gamma^{\prime},X)\gamma^\prime $$
(depending on the sign conventions you are using for the curvature tensor the last term may appear with a different sign.) In the last expression the first term vanishes, cause $\gamma$ is a geodesic, and the term involving the Lie derivate does not appear, again because X is Killing. So you are done.

Comment: Thanks. I see the idea, but you mentioned that the Lie derivative $[X,\gamma']$ vanishes because $X$ is a Killing field. However, $[X,\gamma']$ is a bracket of vector fields; do we not have a problem at that stage since $\gamma'$ is not defined on an open set, or since $\gamma'$ need not be extendible?

Comment: You are right, but, since $\gamma$ is a geodesic it is not difficult to see that $\gamma^{\prime}$ can be smoothly extended locally (which is sufficient).  In that case, if $p$ is a point on $\gamma$, let $V\subset T_p M$ the subspace orthogonal to $\gamma^{\prime}$ and let $N$ be the image of $V\cap U$ under the exponential map $\exp_p$ of $M$ in $p, U$ a neighbourhood of $0\in T_p M$. This will be a smooth $n-1$ dimensional submanifold orthogonal to $\gamma$. Then look at the geodesics orthogonal to $N$ Their tangent vectors extend $\gamma^'$ (... to be continued)

Comment: (...continuation) smoothly :-) This was not your question, so I assumed this as a known construction, since you need this kind of construction to be able to work with Lie brackets of vector fields which are defined only on submanifolds. -- This procedure only works if your $M$ is smooth enough, admittedly.

Comment: If you have doubts that the construction outlined in my comments works out as claimed you will need to look up the concept of the exponential map of a manifold, the fact that it's locally a diffeomorphism $T_pM\cap U \rightarrow M$ locally, and you may need to look up the key words 'tubular neighbourhood' and 'Fermi coordinates', too.

Comment: OK. That sounds good. Just to make sure my understanding is correct, what we're actually doing is: (1) we're looking at a smooth variation $\Gamma(s,t)$ of $\gamma$ through geodesics, and we are computing $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Gamma } \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Gamma }  \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Gamma \right) + R \left( X, \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Gamma \right) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Gamma \right)$; and (2) we are evaluating at $s=0$; the hope is to get zero. Could you confirm if I am on the same page as you?

Comment: Uhm - no, the first term in your formula should involve $X$ and not a 3rd derivative of $\Gamma$ :-). Apart from that your description is one valid approach, but note you'll need an extension of $\gamma^'$, on an open nbhd of $\gamma$. You don't have to extend $\gamma$, it's sufficient to extend $\gamma^'$. The easiest way to do that is probably to trivally do this in $T_pM$ and then apply $exp_{p,*}$ I doubt you can do it without an extension of $\gamma^'$. The thing to keep in mind is that the Lie bracket terms vanish regardless of the extension you choose. This is true since $X$ is Killing.

Comment: After thinking about this for some more time I'guess my statement that you do need an extension is wrong. It must be possible to do all this just along $\gamma$, you need the correct definitions for this and have to derive the formulas for interchanging derivatives. You will end up with basically the same result and the same calculations, though.

Comment: I have a separate question (now linked with this one) that pertains to this kind of argument. Could you please explain why $X$ a Killing vector implies $\nabla_\dot{\gamma} X=\nabla_X \dot{\gamma}$?

Comment: It's not in general true that $[X, \gamma']$ will vanish for your extension of $\gamma'$. As a counterexample let $M = \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\gamma(t) = (0,t)$. Then your definition of $\gamma'$ gives $\gamma' = \partial_y$. Let $X = y \partial_x - x \partial_y$ be the Killing field for (clockwise) rotation about the origin. Then $[X, \gamma'] = -\partial_x$.

Answer (score 2):

A vector field $X$ is Killing if and only if it generates a flow $\phi_s$ by isometries. We obtain a geodesic variation $\Gamma(s,t)=\phi_s \gamma(t)$, and 
$$ \frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial s}\bigg|_{s=0} = \frac{ \partial \phi_s \gamma(t) }{\partial s} \bigg|_{s=0} =X_{\gamma(t)} $$ 
is a Jacobi field.