# Symmetry of Killing Vectors in Covariant Derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Several times, I've seen statements along the lines of "$\nabla_X Y=\nabla_Y X$ because $X$ is a Killing vector field." One example I found on Stack Exchange is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90103/killing-vector-fields-restricted-to-geodesics).

I have yet to understand why such arguments work, and I particularly don't understand what role the Killing structure plays in the relationship.

Could someone please explain this symmetry?

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong. Taking $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the Euclidean metric, let $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $X$ is obvious Killing since the generated flow $\Phi(t,x,y)=(x+t,y)$ are isometric. Let $Y=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, then 
$$D_X(Y)=\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+xD_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$
However $$D_Y(X)=xD_\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})=0$$

Comment: I apologize. I guess I wasn't very clear. I'm looking for a reason why arguments such as the one linked in the question work, when the general case is not true.

Comment: @RawlrusRumbleroar I suspect the answer is that (at least as far as I can tell) the argument in the linked question simply doesn't work.